# how do I make this query run faster?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this SQL query running on a PHP website. This is an old site and the query was build by previous developer few years ago. But now as the site data is increased to around 230mb, this query has become pretty slow to execute. Take around 15-20 seconds. Is there any way I can make this run faster?

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    NULL AS bannerID,
    C1.url AS url,
    LOWER(C1.Organization) AS company_name,
    CONCAT(
        'https://mywebsite.co.uk/logos/',
        C1.userlogo
    ) AS logo_url
FROM
    Company AS C1
INNER JOIN Vacancy AS V1 ON LOWER(V1.company_name) = LOWER(C1.Organization)
WHERE
    V1.LiveDate <= CURDATE() 
AND url = '' 
AND V1.ClosingDate >= CURDATE()
AND C1.flag_show_logo = 1
```

Comment: If columns were added with the values of LOWER(V1.company_name) and LOWER(C1.Organization) and those columns had indexes, I imagine it would be much faster.

Comment: *ON LOWER(V1.company_name) = LOWER(C1.Organization)* Why do you need in register convertion? does the columns collations are case-sensitive? if so then use explicit collation specifying.

Comment: Remove the function on the equality predicate; Is your data collated as case sensitive? If so you need to *store* the data as lower case, by using the `lower()` function you are preventing a sargable usage of any index.

Comment: You do not extract anything from `Vacancy` - so remove it from the datasource and use in WHERE EXISTS.

Comment: Ah.. what a relief. It was the lower() function. Thanks all of you.
I am removing lower() and leaving it to client to make sure and write same company names at 2 places lolz.

Comment: Hi, with the absence of context related to table structure, indices / primary keys, I cannot suggest an optimization. However, you might want to remove the lower function on company_name and organization, and add indices over ClosingDate and LiveDate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As commented, your query is suffering from being non-sargable due to the use of `lower` function.

Additionally I *suspect* you can remove the `distinct` by using `exists` instead of joining your tables

```
select null as bannerID,
    C1.url as url,
    Lower(C1.Organization) as company_name,
    Concat('https://mywebsite.co.uk/logos/', C1.userlogo) as logo_url
from Company c
where c.flag_show_logo = 1
  and c.url = '' 
and exists (
    select * from Vacancy v 
    where v.LiveDate <= CURDATE() 
    and v.ClosingDate >= CURDATE()
    and v.company_name = c.Organization
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Avoid the sargable problem by changing to

```
ON  V1.company_name = C1.Organization
```

and declaring those two columns to be the same collation, namely a collation ending with "_ci".

And have these composite indexes:

```
C1:  INDEX(flag_show_logo, url, Organization,  userlogo)
V1:  INDEX(company_name, LiveDate, ClosingDate)
```

(These indexes should help Stu's answer, too.)